# row with max 2 items angular 9 + bootstrap 4

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Here is my html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div formArrayName="addresses" *ngFor="let address of addressesFormArr.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
        <div *ngIf="i % 2 === 0" class="col-auto">
            <div>icon</div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="i % 2 === 0" class="col-5">
            {{ content1 }}
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="i > 0 && i % 2 !== 0" class="col-5">
            {{ content2 }}
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="i > 1 && i % 2 === 0" class="w-100"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to do no more than 2 items in a row if more then go to next row:

```
icon 1 2
icon 3
```

How can I implement that? Can I implement that with using only bootstrap 4 styles? Maybe I need to use flex?

Comment: you might be overthinking your problem. why are you stating "max 2 items"? just step through your array and display them with 2 items per row. there's no reason to have any *ngIf statements except maybe to ask if item exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div>bla</div>
        </div>
        <div  class="col-6">
            <div>bla</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div>bla</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div>bla</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div>bla</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

use the grid system from bootstrap. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

So something like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div *ngFor="let item of items" class="col-6">
            <img class="iconImage" src="{{item.image}}" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Every row will alwas have 12 col. So when you say 1 item has  size 6, than it will always be 2 in one row.

Comment: I'm already using grid system if you didn't notice, please look at the html in my question.

Comment: yeah, just adapt the code like I show you in the example.

Comment: I also have add now the ngFor iteration. I think now it should be clear?

Answer (score 0):

what you have written seems overly complicated and isn't going to produce good results.

I suggest organizing all your data to have 1 row per object (address) in your case.

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let address of addressesFormArr.controls">
  <div *ngIf="address.icon1" class="col-6">{{address.icon1}}</div>
  <div *ngIf="address.icon2" class="col-6">{{address.icon2}}</div>
</div>
```

then how about this

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let address of addressesFormArr.controls">
  <div *ngFor="let icon of address.icons" class="col-6">{{icon}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need 2 array items per row